# How to load a user specified file in Octave

Tags: octave

I have a very short script that I'm running in Octave and I want to read a user specified text file. It works on my 64-bit laptop, but not on my 32-bit one. The Octave version is 3.2.2.

**plotinfra.m**

```
filename=uiputfile
data=load(filename);
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2));
```

On my other laptop, this brings up a filesystem menu where I can choose the specific file to load. On this laptop, I see this error message instead:

> error: uiputfile undefined near line 1 column 19 error: called from: error: plotinfra.m at line 1, column 17

If I hardcode `filename` with a path it works. I also tried using `uigetfile` and that did not work either.

Comment: do you mean Octave 4.2.2?  Octave 3.2.2 is a very old version and may not have that option.

Comment: If in the hard-coded path works, then most probably the problem is with the way the file path is stored in the `filename` variable. What is stored in the laptop that works and what in the laptop that it doesn't work? Comparing the differences should help. `filename = uiputfile` will store only the file's name. So if you load that file with its name only, it has to be in the matlab path. A better way would be to use `[filename,path] = uiputfile` and then load `load( [path name] )`, therefore to give the full path.

Comment: @tryman I just want to be able to choose a text file that's on my laptop and have that go into the variable `filename`, then loaded into `data`.  If I do `load( [path name] )` is `path name` really inside the brackets? Or is it `filename, path`?

Comment: @RickT It's strange I know it works b/c on my other laptop which has `3.2.2` as well `uiputfile` works fine

Comment: @NaN Yes, it is so that it concatenates the strings `path` and the string `filename` into a single string. For example for filename "myfile.txt" and path "C:\myfolder\" the `[path filename]` should produce a string "C:\myfolder\myfile.txt".
Note: This was a mistake in my previous comment, I meant `[path filename]`.

Comment: @tryman `error: uiputfile undefined near line 1 column 19 error: called from: error: plotinfra.m at line 1, column 17`

Comment: My focus was on how to actually get the correct path because I understood that was what wasn't working. In either case, the correct way to go is `uigetfile` (since you want to read and not right a file) if it works. Have you tried the answer provided by @Rick T ? It's basically the same logic.

Comment: @NaN I Added some test code that you can test with below I don't have 3.2.2 but give it a try and let us know.

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not useful. Please describe what the problem is: error message, failure to load the file, ...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hey Cris, you're right that's not useful, I described the error in the comments, so I'm now moving it into an edit in the original question

Answer (score 1):

[Version 3.2.2 of Octave was released in 2009](https://wiki.octave.org/Release_History). When I enter `edit uiputfile` in Octave, at the top of the file I see the line:

```
## Copyright (C) 2010-2019 Kai Habel
```

Thus, it seems that this function was created *after* your release of Octave. This is the reason you get a "uiputfile undefined" error message.

You will have to upgrade your version of Octave to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 64Bit Linux Octave 4.2.2 see if this works for you.  It will store the filename in the variable `file_name` and the path location in the variable `path_dir`

```
% create your dataset (exampledata) 
x = (-1:0.1:1); 
y = sin(x); 
data = zeros(length(x),2); 
data(:,1) = x; 
data(:,2) = y; 

% save data to file (your textfile) 
save('-ascii','data2.txt','data'); 

%load textfile 
%data2 = load('data2.txt'); %hard coded
[file_name,path_dir] = uigetfile('*.txt'); %pops up uibox choose data2.txt
data2 = load(strcat(path_dir,file_name)); %loads the file and the data

%plot data 
plot(data2(:,1),data2(:,2));
```

Comment: Still getting a `error: uigetfile undefined`, maybe I will chock this up as the version of octave is too old to use `uigetfile` or `uiputfile`